# Building a CI/CD pipeline on GCP

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, automation, google-cloud-platform, gcp

I have a containerized web application on GitHub and I would like to build a CI/CD pipeline on GCP consisting of a trigger stage, a build stage and a deployment stage and be able to do continuous integration and deployment. What GCP tools can I use for this task? I have successfully accomplished the same task on AWS with Jenkins, where my GitHub commit triggers a multi-stage pipeline and deploy the app to EC2.

This is what I have been able to do on AWS:

[image: AWS cicd pipeline]

[image: deployment]

Comment: Hey cristian, you can use [Cloud build](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/) to execute same function as jenkins and deploy your applications in the [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/).

Comment: Another reference: https://cloud.google.com/solutions/continuous-delivery/

Comment: Hey @Tuxpilgrim, could you turn your comments into an answer? Then we could upvote it, and it could potentially become the accepted answer :)

Comment: Okays, i'll Patrick, thks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For building use Google Cloud build. For deployment you can you use Google Cloud Deploy.
https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/ 
https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/